# AnyLogic - stop simulation at specific model time

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I want to stop the model at a specific model time.

Do I have to work with a counter variable per time and then throw `stopSimulation()` or is there another possibility? My simulation will run for one week in model time. I want to stop the simulation 5min before it will end, so 5min before one week of model time is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the stop time in the simulation experiment properties. See below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Emile! But what if I would like to free agents from a wait block at a specific time? E.g. lets say that 5min before the model stops (as you showed in your answer), I want to execute code, in my case free agents from the wait block? I'm thinking smth like `if (modelTime == ...) { wait.freeAll(); }`

Comment: So use Event block

Answer (score 1):

In the settings of `Simulation:main` you can define exactly when you want your simulation to stop.
See attached image:

[image]

To set a week less 5 minutes, replace the number 100 with the number 10,075 (assuming your model runs in units of minutes)

Good luck